# How to load the page without using button?

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to remove my current button that creates JSON table but after I removed button I could not get my table to load. Here is my code:

```
<body>
        <button type='button' id="build" onclick="getTable()">Build Table</button>
</body>
```

and here is my function:

```
function getTable(){
  var one= [];
  var k1 = [];
  var k2 = [];
myTbl="<table id='tbl1'><tbody><th>Selection Box</th><tr>"
for(key in myJSON){

    }
}
```

How I can get my page to load without using button/function?
I tried to remove button and function and just reload the page but that did not work. If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: Where are you executing your function ?

Comment: After I click on the button.

Comment: ...and if you remove the button then when your function should be executed?

Comment: Try this: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',getTable);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onload() on body tag.

```
 <body onload="getTable()">
```

Comment: Don't you think `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered before `body onload` ?

Comment: DOMContentLoaded will surely trigger faster as it waits for only DOM to load. You just should not put your answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery for that, then just use document ready, like this, this will wait untill the document is loaded and then execute the function.

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     getTable();
  });
```

Comment: if you dont want to use jquery @Yaroslav Tkachenko gave you an alternative, but i would add to that that you shold execute that script at the bottom of your body

Comment: You *definitely* don't need to include a massive selector, animation, and DOM manipulation library to subscribe to `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you need to call your function. When you using button, you have `onclick` event, which call your function every time you are clicking on it. The easiest way is to do it like this:

```
<body>
   <script>
   getTable();
   </script>
</body>
```